# Pass attribute to class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I pass `class` attribute to a `class` method so that the attribute will be modified?

```py
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.diamond = 1
        self.gold = 10
        self.change(self.diamond)
        self.change(self.gold)
    def change(self, x):
        x+=1
model = foo()
print(model.diamond)
```

> output:
> 1

I want `diamond` becomes 2.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a good solution for you?

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.diamond = 1

    def change(self):
        self.diamond += 1

model = foo()
model.change()
print(model.diamond)
```

Comment: Sorry for the misleading. I edited my question. I want to write a general method `change` so that every attribute can use this method to get increasement.

Answer (score 0):

Let me say this first that you have no class method, or class variable in your example. What you have are instance variables and instance methods, note the `self` keyword. Now, with that said, you can access and modify your instance variables from any instance method, just like @Almog answered earlier.

The `x` in your `change` method is a local variable, basically it's not available outside your method. As for how you modify a variable by passing it to a function, it's not doable with your code I think. You would need something like a `dataclass`, which you can modify. Check out 'PassByValue' and 'PassByReference' concepts relating to this. Maybe someone else here can help with your particular situation.